# Remove a common word from each string value in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am populating an array dynamically which is based on all the `id`s on the page's `video` tags.

How can I remove the word `dog` from each array item's value? Here is the populated array so far, I just need to remove the word `dog` for each array item:

```
var players = new Array();
$("video").each(function(){ 
    players.push($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

So it would go from:

```
["video_12_dog", "video_13_dog"]
```

to:

```
["video_12", "video_13"]
```

Comment: What would the array look like before and after this removal? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: It would go from: ["video_12_dog","video_13_dog"] to: ["video_12","video_13"]

Comment: Squint that's not my question. My question is not to REMOVE a whole item, but to remove part of it's value!

Comment: You can edit the before-and-after arrays into your question, so that people immediately see it. Will the strings within the array always be formatted that way? Also, people may be reluctant to help without you showing some attempt.

Comment: Super, you've clarified your question. Now how about describing what you don't know how to do. You don't know how to loop an Array? You don't know how to manipulate a string? You don't know how to update an Array index? These are all things that most beginners can do, so which of these beginner issues is too tough for you? All of them?

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time someone used `$(this).attr('id')` instead of `this.id`, I'd be ... slightly well off.

Comment: I am a newbie, I'm sure like you we all had to start somewhere. I looked all over the net to see if someone had done this before and couldn't find anything. Many thanks for all your help though it's much appreciated.

Comment: @AndrewJuniorHoward: Yep, had to start somewhere. I read books/tutorials and learned the basics for myself. You didn't search all over the internet. If you had, you'd have found the answer. And you're welcome. Best help I could give would be to tell you to learn the basics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate over the array and call `replace()` on each element (as string):

```
function removeWord(arr, word) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i].replace(word,'');
    }
}
var aaa = ['value_1_dog', 'value_dog_2', 'dog_value3'];
removeWord(aaa, 'dog');
console.log(aaa); // ["value_1_", "value__2", "_value3"]

var question = ["video_12_dog","video_13_dog"]
removeWord(question, '_dog');
console.log(question); // ["video_12","video_13"]
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9KPkh/